# Merging multiple arrays and get an array of common elements as output

Tags: arrays, typescript, merge

I'm trying to merge several arrays in javascript/typescript in angular, I need to output an array with the common values in all the arrays.
for eg:

```
arrayOne = [34, 23, 80, 93, 48]
arrayTwo = [48, 29, 10, 79, 23]
arrayThree = [23, 89, 48, 20, 63]
```

output: `outputArr= [23, 48]`

for getting common elements out of 2 arrays i'm filtering one array with the element from the next array.

```
return this.arrayOne.filter(el => this.arrayTwo.includes(el));
```

How do I do it effectively if I have to combine large number of arrays....?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is one way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to quickly look up for each value among the different sets.

```js
const intersection = <T>(arrays: T[][]): T[] => {
    if (arrays.length == 0) return [];
    if (arrays.length == 1) return arrays[0];

    const sets = arrays.slice(1).map(array => new Set(array));

    const result = [];

    arrays[0].forEach(item => {
        if (sets.every(set => set.has(item))) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });

    return result;
};

const arrayOne = [34, 23, 80, 93, 48];
const arrayTwo = [48, 29, 10, 79, 23];
const arrayThree = [23, 89, 48, 20, 63];

const result = intersection([arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create an initial set that contains the first array's elements. Then loop over the other arrays, converting them to sets and updating the initial set to retain the corresponding set intersection.

```js
const commonElements = function(arrays) {
    if (arrays.length == 0)
        return [];
    const intersection = new Set(arrays[0]);
    for (const array of arrays) {
        const set = new Set(array);
        for (x of intersection) {
            if (!set.has(x))
                intersection.delete(x);
        }
    }
    return Array.from(intersection);
};
```

Calling this function on the sample arrays in the question:

```js
commonElements([
    [34, 23, 80, 93, 48],
    [48, 29, 10, 79, 23],
    [23, 89, 48, 20, 63]])
```

Returns:

```
[23, 48]
```